# Adding a chronometer to a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel, chronometer

I am struggling with getting a chronometer into a jLabel or jTextfield. My first class is a GUI Where I will want to display the chronometer in a jLabel or JTextField. My second class is where I made the chronometer, which works fine showing it on the console. My question is how can I make the run() method of the chronometer to change the jLabel of the GUI class instead of showing in the console.

Chronometer class:

```
    public void run()
    {
    increaseTime();
    Paciente.tfTime.setText((getTime()));
    }
```

GUI class(Paciente):

```
private void bStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            setTime();
}

public void setTime(String time)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Chronometer chron = new Chronometer();
    timer.schedule(chron, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `setText();` of jlable or jtextfield ..what is the problem ?

Comment: @FastSnail I get the error "Non-static varible tfTime cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: plz post relevant codes here

Comment: @FastSnail the Chronometer works fine if I print getTime() to the console

Comment: use swing timer.can you add more codes

Comment: the error is because tfTime  is a non static field .so you shoud create a object of Paciente class first .add more codes so we can help.see your error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context